# MySQL Workbench import/export: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't Connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (110)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-16.04

Using:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
- MySQL 5.7.17
- MySQL Workbench 6.3

In MySQL Workbench I can connect to my local instance, create a new database and edit this database.
But, if i try to import an sql file I am getting the following error:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't Connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (110)

It does not matter the size of the sql file - even a simple create table and one column with no data causes the same error.

But, If I use terminal:
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql

data imports fine, I can then use Workbench to edit the database no problem.

But, If I then try to export the database, I run into the same problem, but I can export via the terminal.

I am using the root user, with the correct password in each case.

Any pointers would be very gratefully received.. I am stumped!

thank you

Comment: please verify that you are not working on a remote computer (SSHed, may be) while working on the terminal.

Comment: no, no ssh set up, all local. If I make changes via the terminal, they are reflected in workbench, and workbench changes are reflected in the terminal.

Comment: could you show your [client] section and the values of bind-address and skip-networking from [mysqld] section of your /etc/mysql/my.cnf?

Comment: @ffeast my.cnf:
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

 /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
bind-address  = 127.0.0.1
There was no skip-networking setting, just:
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost

I did not see [client] in any of the files in the includedir
But, there was a file: /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = <password>
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: Lets try to explicitly use -h 127.0.0.1 for mysql and use 127.0.0.1 in workbench connection settings and see what would happend

Comment: could you post the output of `sudo netstat -ntlp`

Comment: @ffeast - that did the trick, thank you!!!
Can you add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as such?

Comment: @ice70 done, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be connecting to `localhost` so I would assume that mysqlworkbench is trying to lookup a domain socket in a wrong place. 
Try to switch to a tcp/ip connection by explicitly setting `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html#option_general_socket

> For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the
>   local server by using a Unix socket file. To ensure that the client
>   makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to
>   specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of
>   the local server